# VSCode (or anothers editors) don't recognize sdk dotnet installed with asdf

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, .net-core, sdk

I have the dotnet installed in my machine with asdf, and even the asdf use the `dotnet-install.sh` (this is in code of install of dotnet), the `DOTNET_ROOT` work with the `. ~/.asdf/plugins/dotnet-core/set-dotnet-home.zsh` set (tested with echo in terminal), and the dotnet work and find the sdk (dotnet --info):

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.300
 Commit:    2e0c8c940e

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     arch
 OS Version:  
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         arch-x64
 Base Path:   /home/caneladeouro/.asdf/installs/dotnet-core/5.0.300/sdk/5.0.300/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.6
  Commit:  478b2f8c0e

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.300 [/home/caneladeouro/.asdf/installs/dotnet-core/5.0.300/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.6 [/home/caneladeouro/.asdf/installs/dotnet-core/5.0.300/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.6 [/home/caneladeouro/.asdf/installs/dotnet-core/5.0.300/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

The Visual Studio Code don't recognized the Sdk of dotnet in folder saying that don't have any .NET Sdk:

```
It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
Install a .NET SDK from:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/4582 seems similar to this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C# VSCode Extension try to find the default dotnet instalation path and don't find, in this case you need to point manually the path to sdk with some environment variables in .NET [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-environment-variables). You must define all these variables below in terminal script initialization (such bashrc, zshrc) and show the path to asdf .NET Sdk installation , but can be used to another location, just change the path:

```sh
export DOTNET_MSBUILD_SDK_RESOLVER_SDKS_DIR=$(echo $HOME/.asdf/installs/dotnet-core/5.0.300/sdk/*/Sdks)
export DOTNET_MSBUILD_SDK_RESOLVER_SDKS_VER=5.0.300
export DOTNET_MSBUILD_SDK_RESOLVER_CLI_DIR=$(echo $HOME/.asdf/installs/dotnet-core/5.0.300)
```

And yes the Sdk folder is inside the Sdk folder, I confuse too (This take more time to resolve).

Comment: Thank you!! Just for laziness I added awk and turned it into a sh script: https://gist.github.com/timabell/279823d5433176f24d170ef9c43d797e

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you! Note that the path has changed sometime since this answer was created. The `-core` is no longer part of the path. So the path is now `$HOME/.asdf/installs/dotnet/<version>/...`.